# Do I have to restart/lift Sails each time I make changes to a controller?

Tags: sails.js

In my current workflow, after I make changes to controllers in a Sails project, I have to restart the Sails to pick up the changes. Is there any way around this so that they can be picked up without a restart? (I understand that sails has to generate routes for the actions that I define in controllers during a startup (among other things), but I would like to know what I am missing)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Sails v0.11, you can use the [autoreload](https://github.com/sgress454/sails-hook-autoreload) hook to get Sails to autoreload (without requiring a restart) whenever a controller, model, or service is updated.

This has the advantage that you can build the behaviour into your app and launch it with `sails lift`, as usual, rather than having to remember to launch it in a non-standard way.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you can use forever.js to achieve this. There is a very good explanation there :

https://coderwall.com/p/njcr7w/sails-js-sick-of-restarting-your-server

but basically (and in case link's get down) here is a summary of what it says :

```
[sudo] npm install forever -g

cd /your/project/folder/
```

create a file `.foreverignore`

```
**/.tmp/**
**/views/**
**/assets/**
```

start your app by using

```
forever -w start app.js # -w to watch for file changes!
```

to Stop :

```
forever stop app.js
```

Answer (score 1):

You can, as well, use [nodemon](http://nodemon.io/) in development.
It needs no configuration and it watches for changes in all of your project's files and automatically restarts your application.

```
sudo npm install nodemon -g
```

To run the sails server with nodemon:

```
nodemon app.js
```